# AOT: ngtools/webpack + lazy loading does not work. Using: Angular 4, webpack 3

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I've tried to use ngtools/webpack for AOT compilation. It worked fine until I tried to create lazy loaded routes. The error I get - `Error: Cannot find module './components/dashboard/dashboard.module.ngfactory'.`. In the dist folder I'm also missing chunks for lazy loaded bundles.

I have no idea what I do wrong, I've spent a lot of time to fix this. I've created a simple project `tour of heroes` in [this repo](https://github.com/avmax/playground/tree/angular-aot-refactor/angular/aot), where I get the error described above. The branch in repo is `angular-aot-refactor`. When you get to the root of the app - simply `npm install` and `npm run dev:aot`.

The question is - what I do wrong so lazy loading does not work?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is [the following code](https://github.com/avmax/playground/blob/angular-aot-refactor/angular/aot/configs/webpack/webpack.common.js#L59-L64):

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
    // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
    /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
    helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
    {} // a map of your routes
),
```

To understand why this plugin causes the issue when building aot you should know how @angular/cli produces lazy loading modules. It's very complicated process. But the key point here is that it [relies](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/00ca690807a2326b6e8632a9a0ec46587b841a78/packages/%40ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.ts#L403) on `@angular/core/src/linker` path.

Since you're replacing that path then map for lazy loading modules won't be generated (angular/cli [uses](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/00ca690807a2326b6e8632a9a0ec46587b841a78/packages/%40ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.ts#L418) `ContextElementDependency` for that).

So try disabling `ContextReplacementPlugin` for production build.

P.S. As it turned out it's very known issue:

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4431
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8597#issuecomment-346605655